# Has Occam's Razor famously helped correctly solved some complex problem?

Tags: occams-razor, bayesian

My thinking is that it is not something like Bayes' Rule -- I do not see it as being counter-commonsense. (I think Bayes Rule is almost fundamentally not commonsense.)

If that is not true, that there really have been situations where commonsense tends to be different than Occam's, that would be interesting.

Comment: Occam's Razor is not a rule of logic or a mathematical formula like Bayes' Rule. It isn't used to solve problems; It's a suggestion for how to approach problems. It's not a rule; it's more of a guideline.

Comment: Would heliocentrism qualify as counter-commonsense? One of the arguments was that Copernican system was "simpler".

Comment: @Conifold I believe Copernicus’s initial model was more complex, that being one of the features that delayed its acceptance.

Comment: @ChristopherE It reduced the number of epicycles by shifting the center, those left, nicknamed epicyclets, were small and easier to swallow. But it is always in the eye of the beholder with "simplicity". The delay had more to do with the Church's resistance and the unobserved stellar parallax, that is why Tycho altered the model minimally instead of sticking to the Ptolemaic version.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

NO.  "Simplicity" is far too much of a judgment call and can be readily rationalized.  I have had people argue seriously to me that a multiverse is "simpler" than a single universe.  It also misleads people to prioritize "simple" over "matches all the data".

BUT -- Occam clearly captures something important, so we humans still find it a useful suggestion/guideline.

**Longer Answer**

Karl Popper revolutionized our understanding of science, by focusing on falsifications, and daring experiments, rather than the uninteresting confirmations thru probabilistic accumulation that Hume had focused his understanding on.  Critical test cases are clearly an important part of science.

BUT -- critics of Popper have noted that all critical test cases can be accounted for by tweaks to theories ("theory is always underdetermined by evidence") and sometimes the actual tweak is held in abeyance for decades and a theory is used despite the failed test case (the age of the universe per Big Bang was less than the age of the oldest stars in our galaxy, per stellar evolution theory, for DECADES -- a failed test case for BB theory).

Popper in his last years recognized this critique of falsification, and reached out to Occam to sort between competing theories.  He proposed that a critical test case should be judged between the tweaked versions of two theories, using a rewrite of Occam.  Rather than "simplicity" he suggested that the better theory would be the one with more "predictive power" to exclude possible outcomes.  Using predictive power rather than simplicity is LESS of a judgement call and seems to capture how science operates.

Answer (score 0):

The [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/simplici/#SH1a) offers 2 interpretations of Occam's Razor called the anti-superfluity principle and the anti-quantity principle. Both of them  do not help us create theories (i.e. solve problems), rather they tell us what theories we should accept. For example, lets say there are 3 competing theories in physics called T1, T2, and T3:

T1 - There are 4 fundamental forces: gravity, electromagnetism, color, and weak.
T2 - There are 5 fundamental forces: gravity, electromagnetism, color, weak, and fedhaz.
T3 - There are 5 fundamental forces: tiwes, wrewque, iodne, wondcos, and ewies.

[Just to be clear, fedhaz and the other 'forces' are just the result of me mashing on my keyboard. I am not referencing some extremely complicated alternative to the standard model.]

Lets also suppose that everything one of these theories can explain, the other two can explain, and that everything one of them cannot explain, the other two cannot explain.

The anti-superfluity principle says that we should reject T2 because it is identical to T1, except is has a useless force added in. If the fedhaz force is not helping us explain something, they why bother asserting that it exists. That leaves only T1 and T3 as candidates.

The anti-quantity principle says we should reject T2 and T3 because they use 5 forces while T1 uses 4, and 4 is less than 5. This leaves only T1 as a candidate.

Note that the anti-quantity principle is stronger than the anti-superfluity principle, in that the former can be used to reject theories that the latter cannot. For this reason, that interpretation of Occam's Razor is significantly more common. On the other hand, it is also much more difficult to justify.

If you want a deeper analysis on these two interpretations, look at *Ockham’s razor and the anti-superfluity principle* by E. C. Barnes. I could not find a free version to read, but the section of the IEP article I just summarized draws heavily and almost exclusively from this article.

Answer (score -2):

[Novacula Occami](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)

Scroll down to, interestingly enough, anti-razors, the most well-known being Chatton's.

> If three things are not enough to verify an affirmative proposition about things, a fourth must be added, and so on. ~ Walter Chatton (c. 1290 - 1434)

What I would suggest is to pay close attention to how the *novcula Occami* is stated: *Entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem* (Entities must not be multiplied beyond necessity)

Comment: Please do include relevant parts of links into the body of your answer. Also, I do not see how this answers the question as stated. It only states what the less famous but more accurate formulation is.

Comment: Noted. I did though (see the quote). All I was hopin' to do was provide some background and also what to me is dissent in the ranks. Gracias for the feedback nonetheless.